# Не корректное отображение изображений swiper

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс, foreach, swiper

Из-за использования двух foreach, происходит не корректная работа свайпера. Получается, разные картинки на превью и основном слайде. При вынесении foreach выше, на каждую картинку отдельный слайдер с превью. Как можно исправить?

```
                            <div class="product-detail__swiper--col">
                                <div class="product-detail__swiper-button product-detail__swiper-button-prev swiper-button-prev"></div>
                                <div class="product-detail__swiper--thumbs">
                                    <div class="swiper-container">
                                        <!-- Слайдер с превью -->
                                        <div class="swiper-wrapper product-detail__swiper--wrapper">
                                            <?php foreach ($arResult['PROPERTIES']['GALL']['VALUE'] as $fid) {
                                                $arFile = CFile::GetFileArray($fid); ?>
                                                <div class="swiper-slide">
                                                <img src="<?=$arFile['SRC']?>" data-src="<?=$arFile['SRC']?>" alt="">
                                                </div>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="product-detail__swiper-button product-detail__swiper-button-next swiper-button-next"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-detail__swiper--images ">
                                <div class="swiper-container">
                                    <!-- Слайдер с изображениями -->
                                    <div class="swiper-wrapper product-detail__swiper--wrapper">
                                    <?php foreach ($arResult['PROPERTIES']['GALL']['VALUE'] as $fid) {
                                        $arFile = CFile::GetFileArray($fid); ?>
                                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                                            <a class="product-detail__swiper--link" data-fancybox="gallery" href="<?=$arFile['SRC']?>">
                                                <img class="product-detail__swiper--img" src="<?=$arFile['SRC']?>" alt="">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php }?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

var goodsSliderThumbs = new Swiper('.product-detail__swiper--col .swiper-container', {
        loop: true,
        slidesPerView: 5,
        spaceBetween: 10,
        observer: true,
        observeParents: true,
        slideThumbActiveClass: 'swiper-slide-thumb-active',
        allowTouchMove: false, // Отключение листания слайдера
        direction: "vertical",
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.product-detail__swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.product-detail__swiper-button-prev',
        },
        freeMode: true,
        0: {
            // при 0px и выше
            direction: "horizontal"
        },
        768: {
            // при 768px и выше
            direction: "vertical"
        },
    });
      
    var goodsSlider = new Swiper('.product-detail__swiper--images .swiper-container', {
        loop: true,
        slidesPerView: 1,
        spaceBetween: 10,
        // mousewheel: true,
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.product-detail__swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.product-detail__swiper-button-prev',
        },
        allowTouchMove: false, // Отключение листания слайдера
        thumbs: {
          swiper: goodsSliderThumbs,
        },
        0: {
            // при 0px и выше
            direction: "horizontal"
        },
        768: {
            // при 768px и выше
            direction: "vertical"
          }
    });
      
    goodsSliderThumbs.on('click', function () {
        var activeIndex = goodsSliderThumbs.activeIndex;
        goodsSlider.slideTo(activeIndex);
      });
```